# Use multiple database in same query in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two databases **db1** and **db2** and both of them are same server. my code is

```
public function test(){
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('db1'); 
    $results = $connection->execute('select db1.table1.name from db1.table1 join db2 on db1.table1.id = db2.table1.other_id  where db1.table1.id=10')->fetchAll('assoc');
    dd($results);
}
```

It doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks is advance.

Comment: "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. Please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what _exactly_ you'd expect to happen instead. Show the data that you are working with, the context, the code required to reproduce the problem, your debugging attempts/results, possible errors, etc. - thanks!

Comment: `join db2` isn't going to work. `join db2.table1` might.

Comment: First try to run your mySql query in phpMyAdmin. If you didn't get any result the problem might be from your query.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to do this directly. You have to query both the databases separately and process the results in your backend(controller).

Comment: That's not quite correct, some DBMS' _do_ support cross database queries.